# Group values below a threshold into Other

Tags: r, tidyverse

Given a df resulting from an analysis like this one, how can it be transformed such that it groups all values below say 10 into a "Other" category.

So this:

```
v1  v2
A   50
B   30
C   10
D   5
E   5
```

Becomes this:

```
v1    v2
A     50
B     30
C     10
Other 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess this would do it: using `dplyr` package,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(v1 = ifelse(v2 < 10, "Other", v1)) %>% 
    group_by(v1) %>% 
    summarise(v2 = sum(v2))
```